# TimeFormat always from specific timezone

Tags: java, android, datetime, kotlin, utc

I have problem with date format I create App where I cant format time from current locale but always from specific locale UTC+1 or specific state, but I dont know how.

```
SimpleDateFormat("d.M.yyyy  HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date(date))
```

i need set locale or timezone like constant which not depend on physical position or phone settings.

I have data always in UTC-0 but I need transform it to UTC+1 (or other) and show to users.

Thanks for any help

For time sync I use TrueTime library

Comment: Do you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` or can you use `java.time`/`jodatime`? With the latter a solution will most probably be easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `java.time` example that uses a `ZonedDateTime` created from a moment in time, that is an `Instant` in the mentioned package:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get a representation of a moment in time (not a specific date or time)
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    // then use that in order to represent it in a specific zone using an offset of -1 hour
    ZonedDateTime utcZdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, ZoneOffset.ofHours(-1));
    // and use it again in order to have another one defined by a specific time zone
    ZonedDateTime laZdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));

    // and print the representation as String
    System.out.println(utcZdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
    System.out.println(laZdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
}
```

The output is

```
2020-02-18T14:31:21.714-01:00
2020-02-18T07:31:21.714-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

You can alternatively use an `OffsetDateTime` of the same package.

**The key is to use an `Instant`, derived from epoch millis. Those millisecond values are moments in time, too, independent from zones or offsets.**

You are coding an Android app, so you might have to use the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), a backport of nearly the entire `java.time` functionality for API levels below Android 26.

I think that, nowadays, using `java.time` or a backport of it is the least troublesome and most straight-forward way to solve tasks like yours.

Comment: nice answer but only for API 26+ how i can solve problem for API 21-25? 
Thanks

Comment: @Parad0X thanks, I have described it in the answer, last two paragraphs... Use the backport library.

Comment: oh sorry, I tried it, but i use wrong import for Instant. thanks, the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d.M.yyyy  HH:mm");

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("UTC+1"));
```

Comment: no because i have time(long) in timestamp not in string, i need format timestamp to string with specific timezone.